# get text inside single <br> tag simpleHTMLDOM PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get text from an html file using the simplehtmldom lib for PHP. I only want the text after the `<br>` tag (TextAfterBreak) but only know how to get the entire text between the `<font></font>` tags (TextInsideFontTextAfterBreak in this case). 
I've tried  `find("/td/font/br")` but it returns an empty string perhaps because there's no closing `</br>` tag? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the source html source file snippet:

```
<td>
    <font size="-1" face="Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" color="#330000">
    TextInsideFont
    <br>
    TextAfterBreak
    </font>
</td>
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
$element=$row->find("/td/font");
echo $element =$element[0]->plaintext;
```

And the output:

```
TextInsideFontTextAfterBreak
```

Note: Every table row in the html file is unique so any regex or string manipulators won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode()` it after new line, because `plaintext` strips `html` data:

```
$element = $row->find("/td/font");
$element = explode("\n", $element[0]->plaintext);
echo trim($element[1]);
```

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Thank you :)